# How to import bootstrap 5 bundle js with npm?

Tags: javascript, npm, bootstrap-5

I've some problem with bootstrap5 and NPM.
The website design use bootstrap and works but not all the js (dropdown, modals etc...), I just would like to learn hot to import the js bs bundle without CDN.
Someone can help me, please? thanks for your time

**my steps:**

```
npm install bootstrap@5.0.0-alpha1
npm install popper.js --save
npm intsall node-sass --save-d
```

**Package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "xlf",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "./node_modules/.bin/webpack --watch",
    "sass": "node-sass --watch src/scss -o dist/css --output-style nested"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^5.0.0-alpha1",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "node-sass": "^5.0.0",
    "webpack": "^5.26.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.5.0"
  }
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
   entry: './src/js/app.js',
   output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist','js'),
      filename: 'app.js',
   },
   mode: 'production',
   module: {
      rules:[
       {
          test: /.(scss|css)$/,
          use:
          [
             {
                options: { reloadAll: true },
             },
             'css-loader',
             'sass-loader',
             'node-sass'
          ]
       }
      ]
   }
 };
```

**src/js/app.js**

```
import 'bootstrap';
```

**src/scss/app.scss**

```
@import '../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss';
```

Comment: You are using a `alpha` version. That could be the reason. Try `npm i -S bootstrap@5.0.0.beta2`.

Comment: You can narrow down the JS file in the node_modules 
import  './node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js'

Comment: @jaba: tried with beta version but same result :(

Comment: What is the result?

Comment: modal, dropdown ecc not working...
with my code JS works only if I also add into HTML popper via CDN

Comment: Yes, you have to use popper with the default bootstrap package. That's correct. Popper is only included in `bootstrap.bundle.js` and `bootstrap.bundle.min.js`: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/

Comment: how can i add popper (not from CDN) in my js file? or CDN is the only way?

Comment: You can either use the bundled version of bootstrap or install popper and import it.

Comment: ok thank you, so before the import 'bootstrap' i need to write something like import 'popper'?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved with these steps:

1. installing beta versione
2. uninstalling popper.js and installing @popperjs/core
3. adding `import '@popperjs/core';` before `import 'bootstrap';`

Thanks for help Jabaa.

Comment: You could try without step 3. I'm not sure if it's necessary. It's necessary to install `@popperjs/core` and `bootstrap` should import it.

Comment: That's true, one doesn't need to import `@popperjs/core` to make it work with Bootstrap 5